# Index page in Joomla

Tags: html, joomla, ftp, indexing, joomla-extensions

I have made a homepage in Joomla 2.5, and I need my front page to be different then the page made in Joomla.

My best solution then, is to make the front page in pure HMTL, and then redirect to the site made in Joomla. Is this possible? or is there an easier way to do it? for example with a plugin or something?

Comment: Try to edit your question with more information

Comment: why not changing the `index.php` layout structure ?? you can customize it according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom html page and create it an article and then assign this article to front page. In this way you can display your custom html page to hope page of joomla.
Further if you want to remove even the headers and footers of the joomla page for home page this can be done in various ways

1. Make module positions and display the header and footer in it an
   then in admin do not publish these modules for home page
2. We have
   variable in template index.php which give us flags weather this is
   home page you can use this flag and put a condition like if this is
   home page dont display the header and footer.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand your question. If you want to load HTML only use custom HTML module rendered in your homepage

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? Without knowing more, I have two thoughts.

a. Joomla uses index.php. A lot of the time web servers look for index.html first. So if you create an index.html file and upload it to your root folder, it will display that first and not read your Joomla! site. If that doesn't work, check your web server to see the order that it looks for your start page. That is a setting that can be changed. (Depending on your hosting situation)

or b. You can set different templates for a single Joomla! site. you could set a different template for the homepage compared to the rest of the site. (I just need to know more on what you are trying to accomplish)

Have a great one.